# Method 'layout' not found in view instance livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am stuck on componets rendering whereby am getting the error that layout method not found in view instance

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use Livewire\Component;



class Login extends Component
{


    public function login(){
        return view('livewire.home')
            ->layout('layouts.app');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.login');
    }
}
```

Method 'layout' not found in \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\View

layouts.app

```
  <head>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    {{ $slot }}
 
    @livewireScripts
</body>
```

Comment: remove the : public function login(){
        return view('livewire.home')
            ->layout('layouts.app');
    }

Answer (score 0):

The code is working and "layout" method is right .. but intelephense gives a fake alarm

Reference: https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/2135

You can just add a 'IntelephenseHelper.php' file where ever you'd like (I added mine in app/config folder) and paste this code in it. It worked for me.

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Contracts\View;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable;

interface View extends Renderable
{
  /** @return static */
  public function layout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem. To solve this, go to the "Laravel" menu and select the "Generate Helper Code" option.

[How To generate Helper Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrwQm.png)